# Rnd() returning only one variable in array

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create an array of random sigmas. When I call the below code it generates an array of 1000 identical numbers, please advise.

```
Steps = 1000
Dim ArrayRand() As Double
For i = 1 To Steps
    ReDim Preserve ArrayRand(1 To Steps)
    Randomize
    ArrayRand(i) = WorksheetFunction.NormSInv(Rnd)
Next i
```

Answer (score 5):

Steps is always 1000

```
Steps = 1000
Dim ArrayRand(1 to Steps) As Double
For i = 1 To Steps
    Randomize
    ArrayRand(i) = WorksheetFunction.NormSInv(Rnd())
Next i
```

Comment: Steps is the height of my matrix... in this case it will end 1 Row X 1000 columns.

Comment: But that is not what your code is saying.  every loop you redim preserve the array a one dimensional array with 1000 items, but you are only filling the last slot; 1000.

Comment: Sorry about that, the Steps should of been "i" as in your code, that's a typo - still same issue.

Comment: I answered my question, looks like it was transposed later in the code so it was printing the first number 1000 times. I swear I looked at this for 15 minutes. Thanks for your help Scott.

Comment: @CuriousGeorge the redim preserve is still not needed.  Your code and mine will do the same, but mine uses a lot less memory.